# Python remove the unwanted Dirs from a defined path against a matched list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to match a `months` list with `dir_path` ie `/scratch/rsyslog_CISCO/` and if the the `dir_path` contains any other name apart from `months` lists them just remove it.

I'm able to do that in a flat format:

```
import os
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
dir_path ='/scratch/rsyslog_CISCO/'
for item in next(os.walk(dir_path))[1]:
    if item not in months:
        os.rmdir(dir_path+item)
```

But, i would like it to be covered under definition and main() function, So, what i tried to do like as follows:

```
import os

def dir_del():
    months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    dir_path ='/scratch/rsyslog_CISCO/'
    for item in next(os.walk(dir_path))[1]:
        if item not in months:
            return dir_path+item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dir_del()
```

### The Directory contents are like below:

I only need to preserve `Mar` rest remove..

```
# ls -l /scratch/rsyslog_CISCO
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 15 10:24 KK
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar 13 10:14 Mar
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 15 16:33 nofcs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 15 16:33 tlsd
```

Do i need to define an empty list and the append it matches Dirs to the `[]` late to call in `main()`  function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you want to return a list with all valid directories. Then your could can look like this:

```
import os

def dir_del():
    months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    dir_path = '/scratch/rsyslog_CISCO/'
    valid_dir_paths = []
    for item in next(os.walk(dir_path))[1]:
        if item in months:
          valid_dir_paths.append(dir_path + item)
    return valid_dir_paths

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dir_del()
```

This methods gets all folders in your `dir_path` and appends the valid ones to the list of `valid_dir_paths` whoch will be returned.